# How to print mime payload

Tags: python, api, gmail

I want to get the body from an email and print it on the terminal.

I have got the following code from the google API but do not know how to view the body in human readable text:

```
msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)

print(mime_msg.get_payload())
```

The `print` does not work. Is there a proper solution for my problem?

Comment: What does the print statement produce? No output? An error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Extract the body from a mail in plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967587/python-extract-the-body-from-a-mail-in-plain-text)

Comment: in gmail API, you can use something like :
`content = message['payload']['parts']` then iterate over content :
`[file['mimeType'] for file in content]` to print all mime types